# Can storing all the MySql table's data in an array give performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, social-networking

I am working on a website that deals with user profiles. Every now and then I need to get some data from a table that has the user data. I have applied limits and everything but still i have to touch the table for every usage.
I am planning to fetch the whole essential data from the table and store it in a php array as the page loads, and then use the data from there. Once the user refreshes, the data will change too. I expect that this will help me in not touching the table every now and then on the page. Will this help me improve performance or will it add extra load to the server.

Example, I need to display user's name and image randomly. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is on the better part , if you do provide some codes

Comment: to make application fast , use javascript variable to keep values and ignore page refresh

Comment: initially i was fetching things individually .
now i am using 

$sqlp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY tabid");
 $myArray = array();
 $index=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlp)) 
 {
   $myArray[$index] = $row;
   $index++;
 }

and then printing things as per the requirements from the array.

Comment: Consider starting to use memcached.

Comment: page refresh is not an issue. i need to place the name, country and image next to the content and these data would not change frequently.

Comment: if data need not to change frequently , why are fetching them all at once??

Comment: Sir, I mentioned that these data would "not" change frequently. And I don't want to touch the database every time.

Comment: " it add extra load to the server " , your guess is correct since useless data will be there .One more thing to update any data ,you need a sever call .So at the moment you will need session or cookies variables .Over all these are nothing but overloading the task and decreasing performance

Comment: That `SELECT` is quite civilized, assuming dozens of rows, not millions.  Even if every page is doing the same `SELECT`.  What is the problem?